# RadioListTile inside Listview.builder index in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to set the index of RadioListTile inside the listview.builder but i can't do that how to do it which I want to get the value of this index here is my code

```
         int _value=0; 
         List valueList=[];
         
          ListView.Builder(itemBuilder:(context,index){

            return  Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: RadioListTile<int>(
                                dense: true,
                                activeColor: colorsCheck(),
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                                title: Text(
                                  'Present',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                                ),
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: _value,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _value=value;
                                    valueList.add(value);
                                    print('radio button value present ${valueList.toList().toString()}');

                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: RadioListTile<int>(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                                dense: true,
                                activeColor: colorsCheck(),
                                title: Text(
                                  'Absent',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                                ),
                                value: 2,
                                groupValue: _value,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _value=value;

                                    valueList.add(value);
                                    print('radio button value absent ${valueList.toList().toString()}');
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: RadioListTile<int>(
                                dense: true,
                                activeColor: colorsCheck(),
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                                title:  Text(
                                  'Leave',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                                ),
                                value: 3,
                                groupValue:_value,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _value=value;
                                    valueList.add(value);
                                    print('radio button value leave ${valueList.toList().toString()}');
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

             }
```

Row is inside card where 3 radio button is set (present, absent, leave) but when I click it changes all item builder value. I just want to change the value of that radio inside the card which it clicks. other not. here is an image ...

[image]

look inside the picture where the leave radio button is set only top value but it set all.

Comment: you set _value globally that's why it changed all. you can change value specifically for a specific card

Comment: @JahidulIslam can you little explain it, i set it inside class before buildcontext method if i set inside how i do it and i want to know each card radio button value how i do it.? thanks advance

Comment: these cards are dynamically created after getting data from api which is listview.builder.

Comment: yeah I understood it comes from API and so, you update the list element

Comment: use model class, where every data can be change individually.

Comment: @AlwayssBijoy there is no need about model class because i want to set index in radio list tile widget which i cant if i set index the problem automatically resolve. how to set index in radio list tile in listview.builder ? that's issue

Answer (score 0):

set index in radiotilelist inside listview.builder

```
   currentStatus = List<int>.filled(data.length, initialValue);
    groupValue: currentStatus[index];
   currentStatus[index] = newStatus
```